# Cost effective way to connect microcontroller to internet (not wifi)

Tags: module, arduino, hardware, microcontroller, iot

All I want to do is connect a microcontroller to the internet and send something to my server whenever the micro controller has moved. I don't want to connect to wifi but rather 3g or something of that nature. I am a software engineer not a hardware engineer so as long as it connects to the internet i can do the rest.

Anybody know how I could do this?

Comment: doesnt adafruit sell something that does this.  it is certainly possible, 3g is more expensive naturally than wifi or wired, but certainly possible.  just have to buy the right hardware and interface to it...

Comment: yeah took only a few seconds to find one on adafruilt.  sure there are others as well.

Comment: cost effective is wifi with an esp8266 or something similar or bluetooth

Comment: "All I want to do" - classic under-appreciation of the technology there. Adafruit is probably the simplest way to go - they do cellular Arduino shields that you could bastardise for your own needs. The most often-used approach is to do TCP over GPRS. You're gonna have to get involved with the hardware at some point though, as you'll need to interface from your MCU to the communications module - this is likely to be via SPI.

Comment: @dwelch I've found many ways to connect a micro controller to the internet but all i want to do (and yes I'll repeat that to express the simplicity of what I want to do. In no way am I under-appreciating technology. ) is send the smallest amount of information to my server via internet in the most cost effective way. And I'd like to do so when I'm not on wifi. So 2g or 3g. I've found that adafruit cellular shields cost more than the micro controller itself. For what I want to do I would think it should cost less than $5.

Comment: I've found a project called Lofi(https://hackaday.io/project/1552-lofi) that does what I'm aiming to do except it uses wifi. Any idea how I could use a cellular connection instead?

Comment: well unless you buy a used phone with an interface (the old cell phones had a serial port which would be perfect but I think the old cell system is shut down) anything cell is going to be in that price range and that doesnt include the data plan you will need to go with it.  Basically if you need mobile service you are going to pay for it.  You can go with UHF/VHF/FRS, etc radio service, but you need a radio or a service on the other end of that and that may or may not be free or inexpensive, the radios might be a little cheaper than a GSM module.

Comment: actually if you just go to ebay you can find what you want,  I might even buy a few...

Comment: Have you considered using SIGFOX, instead of 2/3G? In any case, you think what should cost less than $5 - the hardware, or the service provision - what're you basing that number on?

Comment: @dwelch I'm not sure a radio service is what I'm looking for since it is short range but that is a good idea. I'm looking for something that will connect the device to the internet so it can work in most places around the world. But I'll look into it a little more.

Comment: @EdKing I actually hadn't heard of SIGFOX until now but I just did a little research and it looks like exactly what I'm looking for! And I was basing the price on the hardware itself and not the service. I know that'll be more expensive in the long run. But thanks! If you make it an answer ill mark it correct :)

Comment: GSM modules appear to cost only a few bucks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using SIGFOX instead. It has good coverage in the US, and increasing coverage in the UK, and presents a low-cost alternative to communications using GSM. LoRa is another alternative.

Both of these technologies are gaining traction as the IoT grows and satisfy different use cases.

Answer (score 0):

GSM/GPRS would allow you to connect to the internet at the cheapest cost of data bundles provided by your local subscriber, however, you could have a GSM fall back for SMS incase of poor connectivity or just create SMS to server pipeline instead of data.